# newb question: how do i install an .RPM or .DEB on my server?

Tags: linux, centos, jungledisk

*sorry i'm a complete newb with all this server stuff...*

I have access to my server through cPanel and WHM.

**I'd like to install JungleDisk, who provide .RPM, .DEB and .TAR for installing their server software.**

Their documentation says this:

> Package files are available for
>   installing to RedHat and Debian based
>   distributions (e.g., Fedora, CentOS,
>   Ubuntu, etc.).  Others can manually
>   install the application using the tar
>   file.

My server has this

> cPanel 11.25.0-R46156 - WHM 11.25.0 -
>   X 3.9 CENTOS 5.5 i686 xen pv

If i go `WHM > install an RPM` JungleDisk is not in the list of available RPMs (even after i Rebuild RPM Database).

**So,
JungleDisk offers me to download either .DEB, .TAR or .RPM, i assume i need to FTP one of these to my server somewhere, and then what?**

Comment: Contact your hosting provider for the proper way to install this software.

Comment: @chris - I'm on a 'self-managed' server (which i'm slowly learning how to manage!) http://support.jungledisk.com/entries/181923-start-here

Comment: I gotta say, this is pretty scary...when newbs run publicly accessible servers...I mean no offense...I'm mostly afraid for the security of your server...if you're not quite sure what you're doing, it's easy to open up wide holes

Comment: @Jason - no offense taken. The server only has 1 site on it which is a personal one not a money-maker, so while i'm doing my best to learn about security it is not a high-risk server

Comment: Maybe not in terms of you losing your data, but in terms of it being taken over by somebody else without you even noticing, it is.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need SSH and FTP access, upload it and then `rpm -ivh thefilename.rpm`

Comment: thanks james, i'ver never used ssh. Is it Putty i need for Windows7 PC -> linux server?

Comment: Yeah PuTTY is the way to SSH from Windows to Linux. I'm a bit reserved about giving you instructions here as you can do a lot of damage with SSH if you don't know what you're doing (Linux is very unforgiving), but typically you'd SSH to the remote host/IP address on port 22 using the root username and password. Then type `cd /the/full/path/of/your/ftp/directory` and then `rpm -ivh filename.rpm`

Comment: Hi james, this worked perfectly. Thanks for the advice, i'll be extra careful when using SSH which hopefully wont be too often..

Answer (score 0):

There are two major package management systems on Linux.
One is rpm. rpm based distros include:
RedHat, Centos, Fedora (from your list, and many more)

You can install with `rpm -ivh mypackage.rpm` this also provides a progress bar.

The another big player is the deb based distros
Debian, Ubuntu is two from this group.

You can install with `dpkg -i mypackage.deb` here.

Sometimes the package builder even provides a repositories...
If no deb packages is available but rpm is here, sometimes the tool named `alien` can help with the conversion (it should be handled with care!).

If it is a distribution with another packaging tool, you can use the tar file. This usually means that the program will install into `/opt` or `/usr/local/` this it does not integrate with the system as perfect like the first two.